# Can I re-enter Charles de Gaulle airport's Terminal 2 TGV station to catch a train to Montpellier?

Tags: france, paris, train-stations, tgvair, trainline

I will be reaching Paris around 20:00 and I am planning to stay the night at a nearby hotel to catch an early-morning train the next day, to Montpellier. Is it advisable to do so? Will I be able to re-enter the TGV train station at Charles de Gaulle airport's Terminal 2 without security checks or delays or is it only possible to access the station if I don't leave the airport premises at all?

If someone has faced a similar situation, kindly help. I have to book train tickets ASAP and need to select the station accordingly.

Comment: Note that if you pck a hotel in CDG, I strongly recommend you pick one near the “Roissypole” area (CDG Terminal 1 RER station), as you’ll get quick and frequent (and free) automated light rail transport directly to the train station. Other hotels are quite a bit further out so you’ll have to wait for a shuttle, and there are frequent delays on the access roads to Terminal 2, especially in the morning on busy days. Unless you stay at the Sheraton just above the train station of course.

Comment: I am thinking of making a booking at Ibis CDG. I think it is in Roissypole area only, but i don't know about its access to 1 RER station as you have mentioned.

Comment: Warning: there are lots of Ibis hotels in the CDG "area", all with CDG somewhere in the name, but only two are actually at Roissypole, so double-check you're booking at the right one. If you are indeed at the Ibis or Ibis Styles next to Roissypole, it's less than 5 minutes (really, across the street) to the automatic train that will get you to the CDG T2 train station in a few minutes. Some of the others are, uh, quite a distance away (that's an euphemism).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [train station in CDG2](https://www.gares-sncf.com/fr/gare/frmlw/aeroport-charles-gaulle-2-tgv) is not under access control, so you can get into it with no particular hassle, either from train line or from the airport access.

You can therefore leave the airport premises and come back to the train station with no particular security checks.

In particular, going to a nearby hotel and using the hotel airport shuttle if available is possible without going through airside security checks.